# Java Spring AOP with XML doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I'm currently testing Spring's AOP with XML features, but I can't make it work.

Edit:
The problem only appears when the method was called from the constructor of the class.

My applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
  <bean id="aopClass" class="hu.viper.aoptest.AopClass"/>
  <bean id="mainClass" class="hu.viper.aoptest.MainClass"/>
  <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="aopClass">
      <aop:pointcut id="pointCutBefore" expression="execution(* hu.viper.aoptest.MainClass.hello(..))"/>
      <aop:before method="writeAOP" pointcut-ref="pointCutBefore"/>
    </aop:aspect>
  </aop:config>
</beans>
```

My MainClass.java:

```
package hu.viper.aoptest;

public class MainClass {

    public MainClass() {
        this.hello();
    }

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
    }
}
```

My AopClass.java:

```
package hu.viper.aoptest;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;

public class AopClass {
    public void writeAOP(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("This is the AOP message!");
    }
}
```

It builds perfectly, and when I run it, it prints "HELLO WORLD" twice on the GlassFish output in netbeans (I don't know why twice), but no AOP message. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: I would check if `CGLib` is in the classpath? It should be there since you try to proxy a class (and not an interface).

Comment: CGLib is in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use `proxy-target-class` in `<aop:config>` to force the use of CGLIB Proxies.

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    .......
</aop:config>
```

In case you are using proxies for `MainClass` in client, then you would need to refer the proxy to call `hello()` instead of `this`. Refer [this nicely written doc about AOP Proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) to understand what I am aiming at.

Comment: still the same problem:(

Comment: @kompi For testing, can you just call hello() from another method instead of the constructor in MainClass. I do not think it is proxied when called through constructor. In fact if it is proxied then you have to use the proxy to call hello() instead of this operator.